# Test failed with "HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)" since the bean holds previous session value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, automation, spring-annotations, browser-automation

Test running in browserstack, the test initialized all beans with the newly generated driver session as soon as it started. In the event that the session expires, a new driver instance will be generated. However, despite the fact that a new session is available, the test failed because the bean was initialized with the prior value of the session. Is there any way to resolve the issue in the spring context?

I tried using a spring annotation @Refreshscope so that it will re initialize the bean but it didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known error and has been flagged previously too.

Here are the links for your reference:

https://discuss.appium.io/t/http-status-404-incorrect-json-status-mapping-for-unknown-error-500-expected/32228

[INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' with GeckoDriver, Firefox and Selenium through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161283/info-http-status-404-incorrect-json-status-mapping-for-unknown-error-wi)

https://github.com/selenide/selenide/issues/929

Thanks.